# Parallel MPI code in C++ memory errors

Tags: c++, memory

I am trying to understand the C++ code I am working with gives out of memory errors. This is a scientific code with several flag variables to turn on/off a bunch of code functionalities. The code works fine when a couple of functions are turned off. However, when these routines are active, it causes 'Out of memory' situations....

Error file created by Qsub, says
Exit status : -4

job terminated due to one or more nodes running out of memory. The function I am talking about used to work fine until I made some additions. I basically created some pointers, intialize to NULL, create a memory chunk to associate with it, store a quantity of interest in it and later delete []*p

I am trying hard to figure out the source of the problem. I wonder what is causing it.. I believe its some C++ programming error (which I am overlooking due to my inexperience with C++). Is there a way to figure out what the bug is .... where it is or how to resolve it.

Some thoughts that ran my mind,
- use try{ } catch {}
- Run some memory program to track the memory usage in the system (in realtime)
- Any other efficient way of debugging a MPI/C++ code for such situations.

- I Read about something on stacks and heaps and how memory is stored... What the safest way to declare a 2D-array, 1D-array on the fly... pointer based or array definition based..??

Please educate me with your thoughts.

Comment: Try reducing the code down to the simplest example you can.  If you share it here it will be easier for us to read.  Most of the time you'll find the problem when you perform the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

[valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) should be able to give you an indication on where memory is being leaked.